# How to create an Python function able to find the smallest multiple of 8 to handle batch jobs?

Tags: python, function, math

Lets say the function will receive an list of IDs like:

```
ids = [15, 16, 17]
```

In this scenario the desired OUTPUT should be:

```
24
```

Because the ranges will be:

```
1 to 24
25 to 48
...
```

On first range (1 to 24) will accommodate all the IDs (15, 16, 17)

Second example, lets say the function will receive an list of IDs like:

```
ids = [98, 99, 100, 101]
```

In this scenario the desired OUTPUT should be:

```
8
```

Because the ranges will be:

```
1 to 8
9 to 16
17 to 24
25 to 32
33 to 40
41 to 48
49 to 56
55 to 64
63 to 72
73 to 80
81 to 88
89 to 96
97 to 104
```

Last range (97 to 104) will accomodate the ids = [98, 99, 100, 101]

Testing this on OpenAI, the code generated is ALWAYS similar of:

```
def smallest_batch_size(ids):
    max_id = max(ids)
    batch_size = max_id
    while (batch_size % 8 != 0) or (max_id > batch_size):
        batch_size += 1
    return batch_size
```

But cant give the desired OUTPUT for this problem, and after enter more details always occours the classic:

**There was an error generating a response**

Comment: The idea is get the smallest multiple of 8 to send as parameter to batch jobs on IA training, saving this way memory, and at same time, holding all IDs provided on same batch.

Comment: What does *"Testing this on OpenAI"* mean? Please tell me you're not asking a chatbot to write code for you :-(

Comment: You always can paste your code and ask for refactor in OpenAI, if you never have tried  should do it, sometimes have good advices, mostly of times no, and when ask for OpenAI generate code for you, mostly of times you will spend time on explanations than you would have spended coding it xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you're asking is basically "what is the smallest multiple of 8 where all ids (minus one) floor-divided by that have the same value" -- which you can code like this:

```
def smallest_batch_size(ids):
    i, j = min(ids), max(ids)
    return next(
        size for size in range(8, j + 8, 8)
        if (i - 1) // size == (j - 1) // size
    )

assert smallest_batch_size([15, 16, 17]) == 24
assert smallest_batch_size([98, 99, 100, 101]) == 8
```

Comment: If the ids are guaranteed to be consecutive, then you only need to look at the first and last id.

Comment: Or if not, just the min and max id.  :)  Good catch!

Comment: Nice, you got the point, the Ids on my case are consecutive but since you think ahead about non consecutive INPUTS then no refactor code would be needed in future